# Will Win8 improve the performance of an Asus EeePc Netbook?

Tags: windows-8

My wife has an Asus Eee Pc netbook and right now its really a pain to do anything on it because its just so slow.  I've heard that Windows 8 should improve performance some, but I wanted to know if anyone has done anything similar and if the performance gain was noticeable.

I am aware that it will not have a high enough resolution to support Modern apps.

Comment: What do you have installed on it now?

Comment: We need more information to answer this.   What OS is on the netbook now?   How much memory?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I accidentally deleted that.  Right now its Win7 STarter, 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware that it will not have a high enough resolution to support
>   Modern apps.

This means you will be unable to install ANY application sold on the Microsoft Store that is a Modern UI application.  In addition if your system is already slow, it won't become faster, because you install Windows 8.